# How does launcherRootView act as an object below

Tags: android

HI in the code below how does launcherRootView invoke those functions below in android programming and i don't see where the object is being created if it is really an object. 
To create an object you need to use the new keyword something like this:

```
 RelativeLayout launcherRootView = new RelativeLayout()    


   final RelativeLayout launcherRootView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.launcher_root_view);
    launcherRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(newOnGlobalLayoutListener() {
```

Comment: `To create an object you need to use the new keyword` which is exactly what the inflater does when parsing the XML to create the view hierarchy.  What is your question?

Comment: is the object created with this line of code "final RelativeLayout launcherRootView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.launcher_root_view);" ? is this what you mean by the inflater does when parsing the xml

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can initialize views (like your `launcherRootView`) in `xml` file. And then simply get them by calling `findViewById` method.

All magic is done in `setContentView()` method, `Activity` is parsing `xml` file with views and creating objects in it.

For more information look at [android developers guides](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

Comment: "EditText username =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername); " By using this line of code have i already created an object of type EditText called username ?